# Laravel 5.2.45 - empty $errors variable in views

Tags: laravel

**Problem:**

The $errors variable is empty in the views. There's talk that this has been fixed in 5.2 so hopefully the problem is on my end.

**Environment:**

- Mac OS X
- Laravel *5.2.45*

**The Codez:**

Routes.php

```
Route::get('/', 'AlleleController@index');

Route::get('/register', function () {
    return view('auth.register');
});

Route::auth();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');

Route::get('/alleles', 'AlleleController@index');
Route::post('/allele', 'AlleleController@store');
Route::delete('/allele/{allele}', 'AlleleController@destroy');
```

AlleleController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Allele;

class AlleleController extends Controller {

    /**
    * Create a new controller instance.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function __construct() {
        // All methods require authentication except index.
        $this->middleware('auth', ['except' => ['index']]);
    }

    /**
    * Root page.
    *
    * @return Response
    */
    public function index() {
        return view('welcome');
    }

    /**
    * Create a new allele.
    *
    * @param  Request  $request
    * @return Response
    */
    public function store(Request $request) {
        $allele = new Allele();
        // Get all input as an array.
        $input = $request->all();
        // Validate input.
        if ($allele->validate($input)) {
            // Valid input. Write to database.
            // The inserted model instance is returned.
            $result = $allele::create($input);
            if ($result) {
                // Insert successful.
                $message = array('message' => 'Data added!');
                return view('home', $message);
            } else {
                // Insert failed. Send errors to view.
                $errors = array('errors' => 'Error saving data.');
                return view('home', $errors);
            }
        } else {
            // Invalid input. Get errors.
            $errors = $allele->errors();
            // Send errors to view.
            return view('home', $errors);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

HomeController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller {
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index() {
        return view('home');
    }
}
```

Model: Allele.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Allele extends Validation {

    /**
    * The attributes that are mass assignable.
    */
    protected $fillable = ['allele'];

    /**
    * Validation rules.
    */
    protected $rules = array (
        'allele' => 'required|max:20',
    );
}
```

Model: Validation.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Validator;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Validation extends Model {

    protected $rules = array();

    protected $errors;

    public function validate($input) {
        // Make a new validator object.
        $v = Validator::make($input, $this->rules);

        // Check for failure.
        if ($v->fails()) {
            // Set errors and return false.
            $this->errors = $v->errors();
            return false;
        }

        // Validation passed.
        return true;
    }

    // Retrieves the errors object.
    public function errors() {
        return $this->errors;
    }
}
```

View: views/common/errors.blade.php

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <!-- Form Error List -->
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <strong>Whoops! Something went wrong!</strong>
        <br><br>
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

View: views/home.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Dashboard</div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    You are logged in!
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Create New Allele -->
<div class="panel-body">
    <!-- Display Validation Errors -->
    @include('common.errors')

    <!-- New Allele Form -->
    <form action="{{ url('allele') }}" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
        {{ csrf_field() }}

        <!-- Allele Name -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="allele-name" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Allele</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" name="allele" id="allele-name" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Add Allele Button -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Allele
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: I believe your routes need to be behind the `web` middleware group.

Comment: Yes, you better to put all your routes which as validators inside `web middleware`

Answer (score 0):

All validation methods should be placed inside `web middleware` . I do not see any other error. Replace your `route.php` like this.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function ()
{
Route::get('/', 'AlleleController@index');

Route::get('/register', function () {
    return view('auth.register');
});

Route::auth();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');

Route::get('/alleles', 'AlleleController@index');
Route::post('/allele', 'AlleleController@store');
Route::delete('/allele/{allele}', 'AlleleController@destroy');
});
```

Comment: @Sachitch: Thank you. I updated my routes.php as described above but $errors is not being displayed in the view. I noticed [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware) says: "...the web middleware group is automatically applied to your default routes.php file by the RouteServiceProvider." Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure there are errors in that view? basically in form.

Comment: @Sachitch: if I enter a value longer than 20 characters in the text box, according to my rules it should fail validation. I verified the value is not inserted into the database. However, I do not receive a validation error in the view. Very strange.